# Transfer Attributes not transfering UVs [Maya]

Tags: 3d, maya

I'm trying to retopologize an asset (a sweater) created in Marvelous Designer using Maya 2019. Following a tutorial, I created a new flat mesh on top of the original flattened mesh and adjusted the UVs so they would match. After that, I selected the mesh I created and then the non-flattened sweater, and used transfer attributes with the indicated parameters. The problem is, it just doesn't transfer the UVs. 
I've tried re-making the mesh several times, changing the Transfer Attributes parameters, the order of selection in case I was messing that up, but I can't seem to find the problem. It's my first time working on Maya, usually I go with 3dsMax, but I thought that Transfer Attributes would be a very useful tool.

Thanks in advance.

[image: A screenshot of Maya with the sweater, UVs and Transfer Attributes parameters]
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just realized that the vertex number of my mesh didn't match the one in the original sweater. Works fine now.